# How can I fix my navigation menu bar's background color?

Tags: html, css

I have made a webpage and designed the navigation menu bar using by CSS list properties.
I want that the navigation menu style be Horizontal with black background color. So I change the display to block and float to left but the background color does not show any more. I don't know how to solve the problem.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Navigation Menu</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to style the list horizontally</p>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Give background: black property to "li a" element as well

Comment: as sidenote, it would be better to use flexbox instead of the float hack

Answer (score 1):

floats are not graphically included in their parent by default. Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left`:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Navigation Menu</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to style the list horizontally</p>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you insist on using floats, apply `overflow: auto` to their container, i.e. the `ul` element, to have them (`li`) included graphically *inside*  their parent element (`ul`).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Navigation Menu</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to style the list horizontally</p>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `display:flex` to use flexbox instead of the float hack:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h2>Navigation Menu</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to style the list horizontally</p>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used this CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

For HTML used this code:

```
<h2>Navigation Menu</h2>
<p>In this example, we use CSS to style the list horizontally</p>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```